# Retemplating a Button control with custom properties possible?

Tags: wpf, button, styles, datatemplate

I made myself a `TransparentButton` style that makes the `Button` portion behave the way I want it to (mouseover, enabled, etc), but what I haven't been able to do is set the content correctly in the style.  Currently, I manually set everything in `<Button.Content>` for every button, and clearly that stuff needs to go into the `Style`.  I have set the `ContentTemplate` for the style to a `StackPanel` that just contains an `Image` and a `Label`.  The problem is, I don't know how to specify in my `<Button ...>` markup the `Label`'s text and the `Image`'s Source.  I figured that it had to do with TemplateBinding somehow, but I've been searching like crazy and can't seem to find the information.

So, in summary, I just want a consistent button style where the button content is just a `StackPanel` of an `Image` and a `Label`, and I want to be able to create it in my GUI with something simple like:

```
<Button Style={DynamicResource TransparentButton}"
        Label="Click Me" Image="Images/MyImage.png" />
```

Any tips would be much appreciated!  I hope I'm on the right track here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create custom properties like this, you'll need to make a CustomControl instead of just using a Button style.

This is fairly easy, though - just make a custom control that subclasses button, and adds your new properties (as dependency properties).  This will make it stylable, but also provide you the ability to enforce that those properties are always available, with the syntax you're describing (other than changing `<Button`  to `<local:MyButton`).

For details, see the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks, Reed, as always!  :)  I'll look into it now and hopefully it will go very smoothly.

Comment: I guess I have another question -- let's say I didn't want to use a CustomControl.  Is there something else I can do to make the Button element be able to specify the underlying Label.Content and Image.Source values?  Even Blend-specific is okay in this case since this is for a GUI I'm doing exclusively in Blend 3.

Comment: Well, you can, but it's basically forcing a custom style per button, if you want these to change.  It might be possible to do something with an attached property, but I'm not sure how you'd refer to that from within a style (I've never tried it).

Comment: any idea how to get the border around a button to disappear?  I am playing with the Template property and am not having much luck.  I have been messing with the ControlTemplate's ContentPresenter.  Is kaxaml the fastest way to test out template changes?

Comment: I've usually used blend.  You can extract the template for a standard button, and replace it with your own.  I believe a button has an explicit border set - you'd have to just remove that from your template.  As for checking out changes - kaxaml is probably the fastest - although blend is pretty nice, since it has a lot more features.